# Могу ли я размыть фон находящийся за qwidget "menu_pos_"?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyside2

Мне нужно сделать полупрозрачным фон блока  "menu_pos_" а все что находится сзади
размыть. а текст оставить четким такой эффект обычно называют эффект матового стекла.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но к сожалению я смог размыть только widget целиком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint,
    QRect, QSize, QUrl, Qt)

import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QPoint


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGraphicsEffect

class test_mynu(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, arr="", parent=None):
        super(test_mynu, self).__init__(parent)
        self._expand = False                                # - self.__expand ; + self._expand  !!!
        #------menu_pos_block------
        self.menu_pos_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()

        blur = QtWidgets.QGraphicsBlurEffect(blurRadius=5)
        self.menu_pos_block.setGraphicsEffect(blur)


        #------menu_pos_block_layout------
        self.menu_pos_block_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.menu_pos_block)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_pos_block_layout")
        #------menu_pos_label------
        self.menu_pos_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        self.menu_pos_label.setText(arr)
        self.menu_pos_block_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos_label)
        #------ADD------
        lay = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(self.menu_pos_block)



class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    # number of radio
    def num(self):
        return 3
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_animations = QtCore.QSequentialAnimationGroup(self)

        #------centralwidget------
        centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
        self.setCentralWidget(centralwidget)
        #------layout------
        central_w_layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralwidget)
        central_w_layout.setObjectName(u"central_w_layout")
        #------Spacer------
        vs_up = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(17, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_up, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        hs_left = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(327, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_left, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        hs_right = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(326, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        central_w_layout.addItem(hs_right, 1, 2, 1, 1)
        vs_down = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(20, 105, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        central_w_layout.addItem(vs_down, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        #------block------
        block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        block.setObjectName(u"block")
        central_w_layout.addWidget(block, 1, 1, 1, 1)             ######
        #------layout------
        layout_block = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(block)
        layout_block.setObjectName(u"layout_block")
        #------menu_block------
        menu_block = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block.setObjectName(u"menu_block")
        layout_block.addWidget(menu_block)             ######
        #------menu_layout------
        menu_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block)
        menu_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_layout")

        self.menu_but = []
        self.menu_pos = []
        self.menu_by_pos = None

        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_pos_block = test_mynu("menu_{}".format(i))
            menu_pos_block.setObjectName("menu_pos_{}".format(i))

            self.menu_pos.append(menu_pos_block)
            self.menu_pos[i].setGeometry(QRect(menu_pos_block.width(), menu_pos_block.height(), 151, 181))
            menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_pos[i])

        #------menu_block_but------
        self.menu_block_but = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.menu_block_but.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but")
        menu_layout.addWidget(self.menu_block_but)             ######
        #------menu_block_but_layout------
        menu_block_but_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.menu_block_but)
        menu_block_but_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_block_but_layout")
        #------menu_but_radio------
        for i in range(self.num()):
            menu_but_radio = QtWidgets.QRadioButton('{}'.format(i))
            menu_but_radio.setObjectName("{}".format(i))
            menu_but_radio.toggled.connect(self.menu_animation)

            self.menu_but.append(menu_but_radio)
            menu_block_but_layout.addWidget(menu_but_radio)

        # Связывание меню к кнопкам и наоборот
        self.menu_by_but = dict()
        self.but_by_menu = dict()
        for i in range(self.num()):
            but = self.menu_but[i]
            menu = self.menu_pos[i]

            self.menu_by_but[menu] = but
            self.but_by_menu[but] = menu

        menu_block_content = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        menu_block_content.setObjectName(u"menu_block_content")
        menu_layout.addWidget(menu_block_content)             ######
        #------menu_content_layout------
        menu_content_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(menu_block_content)
        menu_content_layout.setObjectName(u"menu_content_layout")
        #------menu_label------
        menu_label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
        menu_label.setText('text, text text, text')
        menu_content_layout.addWidget(menu_label)

        self.num = 0
        self.menu_pos_ter = []

    def menu_animation(self):
        self.num =self.num+1
        self.toggle_animations.clear()

        num = int(self.sender().objectName())
        self.menu_pos_ter.append(self.menu_pos[num])

        # Хитрая сортировка, что сначала вернет элемент с _expand = True
        for menu in sorted(self.menu_pos_ter, key=lambda x: x._expand):
            pos1 = QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() - menu.width(), menu.y())
            pos2 = QPoint(self.menu_block_but.x() +self.menu_block_but.width(), menu.y())

            but = self.menu_by_but[menu]
            menu.raise_()
            self.menu_block_but.raise_()
            if but.isChecked():

                start_pos = pos1
                end_pos = pos2
            else:
                start_pos = menu.pos()
                end_pos = pos1

            anim = QPropertyAnimation(menu, b"pos")
            anim.setDuration(1000)
            anim.setStartValue(start_pos)
            anim.setEndValue(end_pos)

            self.toggle_animations.addAnimation(anim)


        if (self.num == 1) or (self.num == 3):
            self.toggle_animations.start()
            self.menu_pos_ter.clear()

        if self.num == 3 :
            self.num = 1
        print("--x--")


StyleSheet = """
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
#centralwidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget,
#centralwidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget QWidget{
background:#fff;
color:#000;
}
#click_me{
background:#000;
color:#fff;
}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(StyleSheet)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.resize(640, 570) #Size window
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Вот html шаблон того как кнопка должна работать.

```js
$(".menu-btn input").change(function() {
$('.menu_1').removeClass('menu_1_active');
$('.menu_2').removeClass('menu_2_active'); $('.menu_3').removeClass('menu_3_active');
 
 $('.sidebar_menu_1').removeClass('sidebar_menu_1_active');
 $('.frame_menu_1').removeClass('frame_menu_1_active'); 
 
  $('.sidebar_menu_2').removeClass('sidebar_menu_2_active');
 $('.frame_menu_2').removeClass('frame_menu_2_active'); 
  
  $('.sidebar_menu_3').removeClass('sidebar_menu_3_active');
 $('.frame_menu_3').removeClass('frame_menu_3_active'); 
  
  
var name = $(this).val();

setTimeout(function(){ 

$('.menu_'+name).toggleClass('menu_'+name+'_active'); 
$('.sidebar_menu_'+name).toggleClass('sidebar_menu_'+name+'_active'); 
$('.frame_menu_'+name).toggleClass('frame_menu_'+name+'_active');  
}, 1000);


  
  
  
});


/*return*/
$("#block_blur").append('<div class="frame_menu_1" ><div class="full sidebar_menu_1"></div></div>');

$("#block_blur").append('<div class="frame_menu_2" ><div class="full sidebar_menu_2"></div></div>');

$("#block_blur").append('<div class="frame_menu_3" ><div class="full sidebar_menu_3"></div></div>');





/*copy menu */
$('.copy').clone().appendTo('.full');
```

```css
.content > h3{
  padding:10px;
  margin:2px;
}

.title_1{
 background:red;
}
.title_2{
 background:blue;
}
.title_3{
 background:green;
}

.title_4{
 background:url('https://i.ytimg.com/vi/slZdLNewXrE/maxresdefault.jpg');
}

.title_5{
 background:yellow;
}


.menu-btn {
 display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #333;
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index:110;
}

.menu-btn > input{
 margin:2px;
}

.menu > div{
   width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#18182178;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
text-align: center;
  color:white;
transition:  1s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
   z-index:100;
}

.menu .menu_1_active,
.menu .menu_2_active,
.menu .menu_3_active{
 transform: translateX(0%);
}


/*blur*/
.frame_menu_1,
.frame_menu_2,
.frame_menu_3{
z-index: 10;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
width: 200px !important;
height:  200px !important;
top: 200px !important;
left: 0px !important;
transition:  1s;
transform: translate(0%, -100%);

 transform: translate(-100%, -100%); 
  
  
}




 .frame_menu_1_active,
 .frame_menu_2_active,
 .frame_menu_3_active{
transition:  1s; 
transform: translate(-100%, -100%);
   
   
   transform: translate(0%, -100%);
   
   
 }   









/*copy*/
.sidebar_menu_1,
.sidebar_menu_2,
.sidebar_menu_3{
width: 100% !important;
height: 100% !important;
position: absolute;
filter:blur(8px);
-webkit-filter:blur(8px);
top:  -200px;
left: 0px;
transition:  1s;
transform: translate(0%, 100%);
  
transform: translate(100%, 100% );  
  
}




 






/*active*/
.sidebar_menu_1_active,
.sidebar_menu_2_active,
.sidebar_menu_3_active{
transition:  1s; 
transform: translate(100%, 100% );
  
  
  transform: translate(0%, 100%);
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="copy">


<div class="menu-btn">
<input type="radio" id="rad_men" name="red" value="1"/>
    <input type="radio" id="rad_men" name="red" value="2"/>
    <input type="radio" id="rad_men" name="red" value="3"/>
  
  
</div>
  
<div class="menu">
<div class="menu_1">menu 1</div>
<div class="menu_2">menu 2</div>
<div class="menu_3">menu 3</div>  
</div>
  
  


  <div class="content">
  <h3  class="title_1" >text text text</h3>
  <h3  class="title_2" >text text text</h3>
  <h3  class="title_3" >text text text</h3>
  <h3  class="title_4" >text text text</h3>
  <h3  class="title_5" >text text text</h3>
   </div>

     
     
</div>

  
 <div id="block_blur"></div>
```

Мне пришлось с помощью js копировать весь html код обрамлять в рамку overflow: hidden; и синхронизировать движения с кнопками.

Если можно я бы хотел избежать этого способа так как это дичайший ужас.